# Fatal error: Call to undefined function navigator_web() in

Tags: php, html, hosting

I just uploaded my website to hostinger(hosting provider)
.It works on localhost.

I get this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function navigator_web() in /home/u664439336/public_html/index.php on line 45

localhost php version : 5.3.1
hostinger php version : 5.3

this my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistem Pakar Diagnosa Bipolar Disorder</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
<?php  include("library.php"); include("koneksi_db.php");?>
</head>
<body id="homepage">

<!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo-wrapper">
            <div class="container">

                <!-- Logo -->
                    <div id="logo">
                        <h1><marquee scrollamount="10">Sistem Pakar Diagnosa Gangguan Bipolar Disorder 1</marquee></h1>
                        <!--<span>Design by TEMPLATED</span>-->
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <?php navigator_web();?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Header -->

<!-- Banner -->
    <div id="banner">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /Banner -->

<!-- Main -->
    <div id="main">
    <?php
  $page = $_GET['page'];
    if ($page==1)
        include ('halaman_utama.php');

    else if ($page==2)
        include ('bantuan.php');
    else if ($page==3)
        include ('informasi.php');
    else if ($page==4)
        include ('registrasi.php');
    else if ($page==5)
        include ('lupa_password.php');
    else if ($page==7)
        include ('user_diagnosa.php');

else if ($page=="daftar")
        include ('pasienaddfm.php');

    else if ($page=="daftarsim")
        include ('pasienaddsim.php');   

    else if ($page=="konsul")
        include ('konsultasifm.php');

        else if ($page=="konsul2")
        include ('konsultasifm_gejala.php');

    else if ($page=="konsulcek")
        include ('konsultasiperiksa.php');



    else if ($page=="konsulcek2")
        include ('konsulperiksa2.php');         

    else if ($page=="hasil")
        include ('analisahasil.php');

        else if ($page=="mania")
        include ('episodemania.php');
    else if ($page=="hipomania")
        include ('episodehipomania.php');
    else if ($page=="depresi")
        include ('episodedepresi.php');



    else if ($page=="berhasil")
        include ('berhasil_registrasi.php');
    else if ($page=="gagal")
        include ('gagal_registrasi.php');
    else if ($page=="gagal2")
        include ('gagal_registrasi2.php');      
    else if ($page=="gagal_login")
        include ('gagal_login.php');
    else if ($page=="gagal_login2")
        include ('gagal_login2.php');
    else if ($page=="haruslogin")
        include ('harus_login.php');

    else if ($page=="about")
        include ('about.php');
    else
        include ('halaman_utama.php');  
?>


        <!-- Featured -->
        <div class="container">

        </div>
        <!-- /Featured -->


        <!-- /Main Content -->

    </div>
<!-- /Main -->

<!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="6u">
                    <section>
                        <header>
                            <h2 align="center">Beri Komentar </h2>
                        </header>
                         <form align="center">
<div>
 <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama" />
</div>

<div>
 <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
</div>

<div>
 <textarea name="komentar" rows="5" placeholder="Komentar"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Tambahkan Komentar"/>
</div>
 </form>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div id="fbox1" class="3u">
                    <section>
                        <!--<header>
                                <h2>Praesent mattis</h2>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="default">
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Vestibulum luctus venenatis dui</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Integer rutrum nisl in mi</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Etiam malesuada rutrum enim</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Aenean elementum facilisis ligula</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Ut tincidunt elit vitae augue</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Sed quis odio sagittis leo vehicula</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div id="fbox2" class="3u">
                    <section>
                        <header>
                            <h2>Maecenas luctus</h2>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="default">
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Vestibulum luctus venenatis dui</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Integer rutrum nisl in mi</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Etiam malesuada rutrum enim</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Aenean elementum facilisis ligula</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Ut tincidunt elit vitae augue</a></li>
                            <li class="fa fa-angle-right"><a href="#">Sed quis odio sagittis leo vehicula</a></li>
                        </ul>-->
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /Footer -->

<!-- Copyright -->
    <div id="copyright">
    <!--<div class="container">
            <section>
                Design: <a href="http://templated.co">TEMPLATED</a> Images: <a href="http://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a> (<a href="http://unsplash.com/cc0">CC0</a>)
            </section>
        </div>-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Line 45

```
        <?php navigator_web();?>
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't remember any php function with name `navigator_web()`. Neither I found in your code too. From Where this function coming from?

Comment: navigator_web() function from library.php

Comment: show your `library.php` and to check it is working or not. place a `die()`.

Comment: i cant edit my post to add library.php "an error occured submitting the edit"

Comment: have you try placing `die()` in your `library.php`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is that you are calling the function navigator_web() but didnt defined in the coding.You need to first define the function and then call it

Comment: that function from library.php , I already include library.php.

Comment: please include your file like this:                                                                   include 'library.php';

Answer (score 0):

Please add this file inclusion code at php as navigator_nav() is at library.php

```
 Include('library.php');
```